# why is bringSubviewToFront() only working for panning, not tapping?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(tappedView)
```

is working when I drag (pan) views but not when I tap them. My issue is that when I have one view layered over the other, I want the bottom view to come to the front when tapped. Currently it will only come to the front when dragged. Do I need some additional code to do this? Thanks.

Here's an excerpt from my code for more context:

````
@objc func didPan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
            switch recognizer.state {
            case .began:
                currentTappedView = moviePieceView.filter { pieceView -> Bool in
                    let convertedLocation = view.convert(location, to: pieceView)
                    return pieceView.point(inside: convertedLocation, with: nil)
                    }.first
                currentTargetView = movieTargetView.filter { $0.pieceView == currentTappedView }.first
            case .changed:
                guard let tappedView = currentTappedView else { return }
                let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
                tappedView.center = CGPoint(x: tappedView.center.x + translation.x, y: tappedView.center.y + translation.y)
                recognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
                view.bringSubviewToFront(tappedView)
    ```
````

Comment: I assume you are using both a `UIPanGestureRecogniser` and a `UITapGestureRecogniser`?

Comment: Ah, no! That's probably it. Of course! I'll just need to figure out how to use both now. Thanks : )

Comment: try self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after bring subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. It worked when I wrote a second function in addition to didPan().

This is the additional code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureLabel()

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
        currentTappedView = moviePieceView.filter { pieceView -> Bool in
            let convertedLocation = view.convert(location, to: pieceView)
            return pieceView.point(inside: convertedLocation, with: nil)
            }.first
        guard let tappedView = currentTappedView else { return }
        view.bringSubviewToFront(tappedView)
    }
```

HOWEVER, I found out you can also just tick the "User Interaction Enabled" box in the Image View if you don't want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I managed to solve it this way:

> Add a gestureRecognizer to your view and put this in your code. **Don't forget to set the delegate as well when attaching this to the code!**

```
@IBAction func tappedView1(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(myView)
    }
```

> Put this in your viewDidLoad:

```
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedView1))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

If you want to do that from your panGesture check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752568/how-to-bring-view-to-front-on-tap-set-max-min-pinch-gesture-scale-set-screen).